# How can I create a two dimensional array that containts Ints and Strings in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create an ATM simulator in C# and I kind of stuck with the log in. I'm using a class called User which I defined as follows:

```
public class User
    {
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int savingsAcct { get; set; }
        public int checkAcct { get; set; }
    }
```

I've created three instances of my class to represent the three accounts I will be using. So I was wondering how can I make a two dimensional array that will accept both strings and ints.

I think I can use a two dimensional array for the log because I can use a for loop to traverse the array and check the username and password of each account to see if they match. I know I could use a data base or something else but I'm still relatively new to C# so I'm not looking for something efficient, I'm just looking for something that works. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can do: `class myClass{ public string myStringProperty{ get; set; } public int myIntProperty{ get; set; }}` and then `myClass[,] my2dArrayStringAndInt;`

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry for asking but I'm still a bit new to C# and I've watched some tutorials and created some simple projects but right now I'm trying to learn a bit more so this all seems a bit complicated to me.

Comment: What I mean is that a 2D array in C# is `nametype[,]` (where `nametype` is `string` or `int` or `double`). You can also use a `class` to define this `nametype`. That is, you define the array (or the list, or the dictionary or any other collection) on account of a class you are creating. This class can have 2 properties, and `int` variable and a `string` variable; make an array of it and there you have it: and array with string and int values.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with a 2-dimensional array - could another data structure be used instead? Such as `List<User>`? It is unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish with a 2-dimensional array from your question - if you're just trying to store the information in your `User` objects a `List<User>` or `User[]` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might want a `Dictionary<string, int[]>` but you will have to clarify your question. What is expected in each dimension of the array? What is the purpose of the array?

Comment: Don't you just want to store your `User` objects? If so, you need a list or array of `User`, e.g. a `User[]` or `List<User>`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to store my User objects in one place but my objects are comprised of two types of data; strings and ints. Also I want to be able to modify the data since it's an ATM and money will be moved in and taken out of the accounts. Will using User [] allow make a list with all my users?

Comment: Yes it will, though I recommend learning how to use `List<User>`, it's much more flexible.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how that's done? As I said I'm still learning C#. I'm coming from Python and C# is something totally new to me and it's not as simple, even though so far I'm liking it a lot more.

Comment: @Sebastian See my implementation below

Comment: @coderealm There's no need to ask people to look at your posts, they will see them.

Comment: @DavidG I have only recently started answering questions here, Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looking to store your `User` objects, then keep them in that format rather than trying to squeeze them uncomfortably into some sort of string/int combo. So lets seay you have 3 user objects:

```
var bob = new User { userName = "Bob" };
var alice = new User { userName = "Alice" };
var marvin = new User { userName = "Marvin" };
```

Let's put them into a [`List<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var users = new List<User> { bob, alice, marvin };
```

And now you can loop around it as you wish:

```
foreach(var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.userName);
}
```

And if you wanted to find a specific item, you can get it quickly:

```
var user = users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName = "Bob");
if (user != null)
{
    //We found a user called Bob
}
```

Or even check specifically for username and password:

```
var userIsValid = users.Any(u => u.userName = "Bob" && u.password = "secret");
```

Comment: This is pretty useful and simple. Thanks. Now I just have to adapt it so it works with Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You should really learn some basics of working with databases. Your `User` class is something that is called *Model* and what you're looking for is collection.

First of all i'd recommend to add `id` field to make it easier to identify each object (though it's optional):

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int savingsAcct { get; set; }
    public int checkAcct { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use `List<User>` :

```
List<User> users = new List<User>()
{
   new User() { id = 0, userName = "Alex", etc... }
   new User() { id = 1, userName = "Joshua", etc... }
   new User() { id = 2, userName = "Phil", etc... }
};
```

To find user with specific userName you'd have to use LINQ here :

```
//                returns null if no such user is found
User alex = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userName == "Alex");
```

---

Sometimes it's more suitable to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` than `List<T>` :

```
Dictionary<string, User> users = new Dictionary<string, User>()
{
   { "Alex", new User() { id = 0, userName = "Alex", etc... } },
   { "Joshua", new User() { id = 1, userName = "Joshua", etc... } },
   { "Phil", new User() { id = 2, userName = "Phil", etc... } },
};
```

Then you can access users by their userName with help of indexer :

```
User alex = users["Alex"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows a working example, but will need to be massaged into your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class User
    {
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public int savingsAcct { get; set; }
        public int checkAcct { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // here you'll take the user and password from the form
            string userNameEnteredIntoScreen = "???";
            string passwordEnteredIntoScreen = "???";

            // build list of valid users (amend to suit)
            var users = new List<User>();
            users.Add(new User
            {
                userName = "user1",
                password = "abc",
                savingsAcct = 1,
                checkAcct = 2,
            });
            users.Add(new User
            {
                userName = "user2",
                password = "xyz",
                savingsAcct = 3,
                checkAcct = 4,
            });

            // then to check if they're valid
            var user = users.SingleOrDefault(u =>
                u.userName == userNameEnteredIntoScreen &&
                u.password == passwordEnteredIntoScreen
                );

            if (user != null)
            {
                // the user and password was valid, and 'user' variable
                // now contains the details of the user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, you are looking for a collection that can store `User` objects in your application.

If you need to be able to change the contents of the collection, a `List<T>` is a good choice - it does not have a fixed size so it is easy to add and remove objects.

```
List<User> _allUsers = new List<User>();
_allUsers.Add(/* user object */); //populate the list with Users using .Add()

foreach (var user in _allUsers)
{
    if(user.userName == someInputVariable && user.passWord == someOtherInputVariable)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

[MSDN documentation for `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could also use a 1-dimensional array of `User` but I think a `List<T>` makes more sense for what you are trying to do, and it is very easy to work with as someone who is just starting to learn the language.

Answer (score -1):

In C#, You cannot create a two dimensional array with two different data types, in your case, int and string. You can only create a two dimensional array of the same data type.

If you require a data structure to hold two data types, you can use a Dictionary pairs.

```
//e.g.
Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>
{ 
   {1, "value 1"},
   {2, "value 2"},
   {3, "value 3"}
};


//With your POCO can create a Dictionary as below
Dictionary<int, User> data = new Dictionary<int, User>
{ 
   {1, new User{ userName = "username1", password = "password1", savingsAcct  = 1,checkAcct = 1 }},
   {2, new User{ userName = "username2", password = "password2", savingsAcct  = 1,checkAcct = 2 }},
   {3, new User{ userName = "username3", password = "password3", savingsAcct  = 1,checkAcct = 3}}
};
```

You can use a loop to initialize your dictionary